# Cable Parameters from Specs Data

Tags: cables, model

From a 2019 specsheet for a i.e. [Belden 1583A](https://catalog.belden.com/techdata/EN/1583A_techdata.pdf) cable, I can read \$Z_0=100 \pm15 \Omega \$ for \$f=1 \text{MHz}\$, \$\text{VF}=0.7\$, \$\text{R}=93.8 \Omega/\text{km} \$, among maximum Delay, Attenuation, and others.

If I should obtain the lumped per meter R (already given), C and L parameters for a simple transmission line model, should it be correct to take?:

$$
VF=\frac{1}{c \sqrt{LC}}, \ 
Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}} \\
C=\frac 1c\frac{1}{\text{VF}}\frac{1}{Z_0} ,\ 
L=Z_0\frac 1c \frac{1}{\text{VF}}
$$

Is \$VF\$ in the specsheet ("Velocity Propagation Factor") indeed the Velocity Factor I am thinking?

The specified capacitances are the Non Mutual Capacitance \$C_{NM}\$ and the Maximum Unbalance Capacitance \$C_{MU}\$.

Anyway, what are the meaning of those last capacitances?

Comment: Zo = sqrt( L / C), so you need the capacitance per meter.

Comment: Should I take \$C=\frac{1}{c \ VF \ Z_0}\$ from the equation of \$Z_0\$ and \$VF\$? Is that the proper way to do that in here? Is the Velocity Propagation from these Belden specsheet truly the \$VF\$ parameter?...